# TextBox Binding in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, textbox

hi hello every one am very very new to ASP .net MVC3 here am not getting how to display the data in text-box/text area which is coming from a database. this is my controller code

```
public ActionResult StartTest(int Id)
    {
        TakeTest objTakeTest = new TakeTest();
        objTakeTest.Id = Id;
        var objTestdata = objTakeTestModel.GetTakeTestData(objTakeTest);
        foreach (TakeTest item in objTestdata)
        {
            objTakeTest.Question = item.Question;
        }
        return View(objTakeTest);

    }
```

this is my dataaccesscode where am getting the data from database using entityframe work

```
public List<TakeTest> GetTestQuestionsData()
    {
        ObjectResult<RetrieveTestQuestions_Result3> TestQuestions =   objHLSToolDBEntities.RetrieveTestQuestions(obj.TestId);
        TakeTest objTest = new TakeTest();
        foreach (RetrieveTestQuestions_Result3 value in TestQuestions)
        {
            objTest.QNo = value.Qno;
            objTest.Question = value.Question;
            objTest.OptionA = value.OptionA;
            objTest.OptionB = value.OptionB;
            objTest.OptionC = value.OptionC;
            objTest.OptionD = value.OptionD;
            objTest.TestId = value.TestId;
            TakeTestList.Add(objTest);
        }
        return TakeTestList;
    }
```

am getting all the data which is required but here am not getting how to show in view.i have tried in many many ways but i didnt get that so kindly i request you to please help me to achieve this. thanks in advance

Comment: You are loading the data just fine, where is your view code?

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Question) are u using this in view ? where m is ur returned model for binding model to view

Comment: @NickLarsen not sure if data is loading fine, i'd like to know where ``TakeTest item in ViewBag.objTestdata`` ViewBag comes from, cause normally you would assign it here, not iterate over it.

Comment: sorry by mistake i just added viewbag...the statement is like this TakeTest item in objTestdata

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@model ModelNamewithFullPath

  @foreach (var item in Model.TakeTest )
  {
      <ul><li>@item.Question</li></ul>
  }
```

Updated

```
   @Html.TextAreaFor(model=> model.Question)
```

Comment: Thanks for giving ideas but its not showing any data in textbox please guide me to achieve this......

Comment: This is my view code...@Html.TextAreaFor(objTakeTest => objTakeTest.Question)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@model YourModelName

<Div>

  @foreach (var item in Model.TakeTest )
  {
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => @item.Question)
  }

</Div>
```